# graph places y values chronologicaly instead of from min to max value

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, yaxis

I'm plotting a graph using the database values for temperature, pressure and humidity. The y axis values are all messed up. Hod do I fix it?

```
def plot_graph():
    time_arr = [date.date for date in qry.all()]

    temp_arr = [temp.temp for temp in qry.all()]
    humid_arr = [humid.humidity for humid in qry.all()]
    pressure_arr = [press.pressure for press in qry.all()]
  

    p1 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (0, 0), colspan=2)
    p2 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (0, 2), rowspan=3, colspan=2)
    p3 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (1, 0), rowspan=2)

    p1.bar(time_arr, temp_arr, color = 'r', label = 'Temperature', width=1)
    p2.bar(time_arr, humid_arr, color = 'b', label = 'Humidity', width=0.5)
    p3.plot(time_arr, pressure_arr, color = 'g', label = 'Pressure')

    p1.set_ylim(min(temp_arr), max(temp_arr))

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

[Plot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQweK.jpg)

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/faq/howto_faq.html#why-do-i-have-so-many-ticks-and-or-why-are-they-out-of-order

Comment: thank you both, the values as strings was the issue.